# how can i swap list in a matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, swap

I want to shuffle 3D matrix's rows but it doesn't work in a matrix
here is some example code

```
def shuffle(data,data_size):
    for step in range(int(1*data_size)):
        selected = int(np.random.uniform(0,data_size))
        target = int(np.random.uniform(0,data_size))   

        print(data)
        if selected!=target:
            data[selected], data[target] = data[target], data[selected]            

            print(selected," and ",target, " are changed")
    return data

data = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]],
        [[2,2,3,4],[2,2,3,5],[2,2,3,6]],
        [[3,2,3,4],[3,2,3,5],[3,2,3,6]] ]

data = np.array(data)
data = shuffle(data,3)
```

in this code I want to shuffle data from some row list to another row list

but it's result doesn't work swaping but overwriting

here is result

```
[[[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]

 [[3 2 3 4]
  [3 2 3 5]
  [3 2 3 6]]]
2  and  1  are changed
[[[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]]
1  and  0  are changed
[[[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]]
0  and  2  are changed
[[[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]

 [[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]]
2  and  1  are changed
```

how can i swap list in matrix?

thanks

Comment: The result you posted is from your current, non-working code, right? Can you please post an example of what you think your output should look like? It'll make it a lot easier to figure out a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def shuffle(data,data_size):
    for step in range(int(1*data_size)):
        selected = int(np.random.uniform(0,data_size))
        target = int(np.random.uniform(0,data_size))   

        print(data)
        if selected!=target:

            data[[selected, target]] = data[[target, selected]]      

            print(selected," and ",target, " are changed")
    return data

data = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]],
        [[2,2,3,4],[2,2,3,5],[2,2,3,6]],
        [[3,2,3,4],[3,2,3,5],[3,2,3,6]] ]

data = np.array(data)
data = shuffle(data,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shuffle along the first axis, just use `np.random.shuffle`:

```
data = np.array([
    [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]],
    [[2,2,3,4],[2,2,3,5],[2,2,3,6]],
    [[3,2,3,4],[3,2,3,5],[3,2,3,6]]
])

np.random.shuffle(data)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[[3 2 3 4]
  [3 2 3 5]
  [3 2 3 6]]

 [[1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]
  [1 2 3 6]]

 [[2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]
  [2 2 3 6]]]
```

If you want to shuffle along any other axis in `data`, you can shuffle the array view returned by `np.swapaxes`. For example, to shuffle the rows of the inner 2D matrices, do:

```
swap = np.swapaxes(data, 1, 0)
np.random.shuffle(swap)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3 6]
  [1 2 3 4]
  [1 2 3 5]]

 [[2 2 3 6]
  [2 2 3 4]
  [2 2 3 5]]

 [[3 2 3 6]
  [3 2 3 4]
  [3 2 3 5]]]
```